# Android studio variable incrementation issues

Tags: java, android, variables, android-studio, increment

I'm having issues with variable `c`. An error:

> Error:(34, 17) error: cannot assign a value to final variable c

keeps annoying me all the time. I am a fresh android studio user and I want to fix this problem. Underlined with red `c` is in only within the `onClick` method where I want to increment it.

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.MenuItem;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.ImageView;


public class plane extends ActionBarActivity {
public final int c=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_plane);
    final ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv);


    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.pe1);


    Button next=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_next);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(c==0){
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.pe2);
            c=c+1;}

            if (c==1){
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.pe3);
                c=c+1;}
            if (c==2){
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.pe4);
                c=c+1;}
            if (c==3){
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.pe5);
                c=c+1;}
        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_plane, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4

Answer (score 5):

Declartion `final` means that a value to that variable can be assigned only once. Remove it to fix your problem.

Change

```
public final int c = 0;
```

To

```
public int c; // You don't need = 0 as Java assigns that value by default
```

Answer (score 2):

From the official documentation :

**Final Variables**

> A variable can be declared final. A final variable may only be
>   assigned to once. Declaring a variable final can serve as useful
>   documentation that its value will not change and can help avoid
>   programming errors.

That means, you can't change the value of `c` since you declared the variable as `final`.

So, change

```
public final int c=0;
```

to

```
public int c=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the `final` modifier but I think you have more serious problem which is the logic inside `onClick`. Once it is clicked all the if blocks will be executed because every if condition is satisfied by the addition of 1 to `c`. Are you sure ? I think what you want is something like this:

```
switch (c){
   case 0: img.setImageResource(R.drawable.pe2);break;
   case 1: img.setImageResource(R.drawable.pe3);break;
   ...
} 
c++;
```

Answer (score 0):

When a variable is declared with `final` it pretty much means that it is a constant, and that it's value cannot be changed. Btw, where are you even declaring it?